# Seeing java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in C# code

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf, soap

We are a Microsoft shop and use C# exclusively. We have a Windows Service that runs and sends WCF SOAP requests to one of our production application servers. Those application servers in turn make a call out to a 3rd party SOAP endpoint. In our Windows Service logs we started noticing some `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exceptions that seem to succeed on a retry. `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is a Java language exception, so my initial thought was that one of the 3rd party SOAP endpoints that we call was written in Java and was returning that exception. We then wrapped all calls to 3rd party services in a try-catch, and throw a new wrapper exception with a description of which endpoint was being called when the exception occurred, along with adding the inner exception to it.

However, after doing this we are still seeing the same exception being thrown without the outer wrapper exception on it, so it is not happening when calling a 3rd party service. The only other thing our C# code does is read from a SQL database using the `System.Data` assembly, which I'm fairly confident is written in C# (or C++) and not Java.

The exception stack trace ends at the Windows Service's function to call the application server; We don't see any of the application server code in the stack trace of the exception caught on the Windows Service. Also, this error seems to happen intermittently, I'm *guessing* when there is lots of traffic, so it's not easy to reproduce. Out of thousands of requests a day, we might see it happen 50 times.

So I'm kind of at a loss from where this exception is coming from. It's possible that our production load balancer (F5) and/or firewall product (Cisco ASA) are written in java, but I wouldn't expect their exception details to leak into the exception I'm seeing; I would instead expect a regular C# "connection failed/lost" exception.

Our application servers are Windows 2012 R2 using IIS 8, and we are running ASP.Net WCF SOAP services.

Any thoughts/ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

### Update

It turns out that we had some code that was actually unwrapping the original exception and throwing it back with a truncated stack trace. So the problem was originating from calling a 3rd party service that is written in Java after all; we were just doing something dumb with our error handling. Mystery solved.

Comment: Which application server are you using, and what kind of a request is made to the server by the Windows Service?

Comment: Check the counterpart logs, they should have something

Comment: @MickMnemonic We are using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2, and running ASP.NET WCF services. The request is a WCF SOAP request from the Windows Service to the Application Server. I've updated my question to include this info. Thanks.

Comment: @efekctive I assume you mean I should check the Application Server's logs. This is easier said then done, as we have tens of servers load balanced, so I don't necessarily know which server the error occurred on. Also, it is hard to reproduce and seems to happen intermittently :(

Comment: Yes. It was an idea. Maybe a super grep session :-}